# Rspec mailer test with devise link

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, devise

I have custom UserMailer, which have devise link- edit_password_path. Now  I need write tests:

```
require "rails_helper"

RSpec.describe UserMailer, type: :mailer do

  describe "#invitation" do
    let!(:user) { create(:user) }
    let!(:correspondence) { create(:correspondence) }
    let!(:mail) { UserMailer.invitation(user, user.password) }

    it "renders the headers" do
      expect(mail.subject).to eq(correspondence.invitation_subject)
      expect(mail.to).to eq(user.email)
    end
   end
end
```

error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `edit_password_url' for #<UserMailer:0x005604b3309248>
```

How Can I include urls to my mailer tests in rspec?

Comment: have you a path to `edit_password`?

Comment: explicitly you can add url helpers as follows `include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers` (in rails_helper) but they shell be already added...

Comment: edit_password_path is working correctly when I look this manually in development mode, including routes.url_helpers not helping in this situation.

Comment: seems the problem is in groups of Gemfile... try to move all of :test group, or from :development to pair :test, :development, and rerun

Comment: OK, I must include to UserMailer.rb `include Devise::Controllers::UrlHelpers` and it works great. Thank's for help(specially tip to include something which help me :D ! )